# Error in query (1052): Column 'register_log_id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, database

The POS software I use has recently updated and split the info I need to download into 2 tables. I thought I had the issue sorted but I'm getting the error in the title. 
Here is the code:

```
SELECT register_log_id, p.register_id, p.employee_id_open, 
p.employee_id_close, p.shift_start, p.shift_end, s.open_amount, 
s.close_amount, s.payment_sales_amount, s.total_payment_additions, 
s.total_payment_subtractions, p.notes 
FROM phppos_register_log p JOIN
phppos_register_log_payments s
ON p.register_log_id = s.register_log_id
WHERE shift_end <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND register_log_id > 2607
```

Comment: Ambigous means that some other table you are using must have the field 'register_log_id' as well. Try giving your tables aliases: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/alias. Sorry, just saw you've already done that. I guess, use them then :)

Answer (score 1):

In the `WHERE` clause you need to add the alias to `register_log_id` so MySQL knows which table you are trying to limit it by.

So either:

```
WHERE shift_end <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND p.register_log_id > 2607
```

or

```
WHERE shift_end <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND s.register_log_id > 2607
```

You don't have the issue with `shift_end` because it must only be in one of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

> Column 'register_log_id' in field list is ambiguous

This simply means `register_log_id` is not an unique column name and exists in more than one table you are referencing in your query. Simply prefix that field with table name and you are done.

Comment: I've tried this and I'm still getting the same error:

    SELECT phppos_register_log.register_log_id, p.register_id, 
    p.employee_id_open, p.employee_id_close, p.shift_start, p.shift_end, 
    s.open_amount, s.close_amount, s.payment_sales_amount, 
    s.total_payment_additions, s.total_payment_subtractions, p.notes 
    FROM phppos_register_log p JOIN
   phppos_register_log_payments s
   ON p.register_log_id = s.register_log_id
   WHERE shift_end <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND p.register_log_id > 2607

Comment: Once you've aliased a table, it's best to keep it consistent; `SELECT p.register_log_id, ...`

Answer (score 0):

> Column `register_log_id` in field list is ambiguous

That means that the column: `register_log_id` appears in more than one table.
Simply fully qualify it as: `tableName.tableColumn`